# JPA - When to use getTransaction() when persisting objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions

I've recently started working with JPA on the Google App Engine. In reading some examples, I've noticed a couple of variations in the way objects are persisted. In one case, I've seen something like this:

```java
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(object);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

In other cases, I don't see the use of `getTransaction()`. I simply see `entityManager.persist(object)`. When is it appropriate to use `getTransaction()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use container managed `EntityManager` then you're using JTA transactions. Hence, you don't need to (more precisely - you can not) interfere with `EntityManager`'s transactions fetched using `entityManager.getTransaction()`. The JTA starts and commits your transaction.

If you use application managed `EntityManager` and you don't want to be in part of JTA transaction, then you need to manage them for yourself (it's called a resource-local entity manager).

Most typically, application managed `EntityManager` which works with `EntityManager.getTransaction()` is used in Java SE environment.

EDIT: You might be interested in secion **7.5 Controlling Transactions** from the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Comment: Never worked with GAE - thought this is more JPA-transaction centric question. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: do we need get transaction even when getting entity from database...using entitymanager.find method...just curious..because i am not able see even a single example..where with transaction.begin() before entitymanger.find method...:) :)

Answer (score 5):

In GAE there is no Java EE/JTA so ignore terms such as bean managed transaction (BMT), and container managed transactions (CMT).

Your work is either transactional (where you want multiple objects to go to the datastore at once, or all to fail - this is where you have getTransaction() used), or nontransactional (where everything goes to the datastore one by one, and the failure of one persist doesn't affect others - this is where you just call persist()/merge()/remove()).

Comment: There are some parts of Java EE in GAE, just not any complete profile. JPA for instance is a Java EE API, but it's behavior is a 'little different'.

Answer (score 4):

Google App Engine has its transaction management (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) but the JPA  transaction interface isn't aware of some of the GAE underlying functionalities (i.e. entity groups).

**So it’s up to your application to decide which operations to perform in a transaction and which not.** 
You should put in a transaction operations that have to be executed atomically.

Remember as a best practice to perform cascading actions and relationship operations in a transaction because JPA might trigger many queries and it could lead to an inconsistent data situation.

Example of using transaction with JPA2:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;


EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
txn.begin();
try {
    //do something with your database
    txn.commit();
} 
finally {
   if (txn.isActive())
      txn.rollback(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `getTransaction()` when you're explicitly handling the transactions in your application. On the other hand, if you let the container handle the transactions for you, it won't be necessary to explicitly begin/end transactions. Essentially, we're dealing with the difference between [Container Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) (CMT) and [Bean Managed Transactions](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction4.html) (BMT).

In general, you'd use BMT when you need more control over the transactional processing, or when there are additional technical requirements (for instance, two-phase commits, distributed transactions, XA transactions) that can't be met by using CMT. Also, you'd use BMT when your applications is deployed outside of an application server and relies on Java SE.