# JPA: How can I ensure that attribute values of a managed entity are written to the database in a transactional way?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

It seems like a pretty basic question to me, so probably I'm either lacking the right search terms or I'm completely missing something about the way how managed entites work, but nevertheless I was unable to find out how to do this: Writing new attribute values of a managed entity to the database in a transactional way, meaning I want to set a bunch of values to an entity bean and have them persisted all at once and without other threads seeing a „dirty“ intermediate state of the bean or interrupting the writing process.

This is the entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntityClass
{
    ...
    private String status;
    private String value;
    ...
    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
    ...
    public void setValue(String vlaue)
    {
    ...
}
```

I'm using it here:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyService
{
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
    MyEntityClass entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);

    //Now I'd like to set some attributes in a transactional way
    entity.setStatus(newStatus);

    //what if the new status got persisted and another thread reads from the database now
    entity.setValue(newValue);

    //flushing, just to make sure that at least from here on the database is in a consistent state
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

I need to ensure that no other thread can see the entity in a „half-written“ state, i.e. with the new status already persisted but the old value still present in the database. I tried using a lock:

```
...
MyEntityClass entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.WRITE);
entity.setStatus(newStatus);
entity.SetValue(newValue);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.lock(entity, LockTypeMode.NONE);
...
```

But this throws:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entity not in the persistence context` 
because the transaction used for reading the entity ends after the `entityManager.find()` is completed and therefore also the persistence context is gone, as I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191528/3716035).

Also, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464370/jpa-when-to-use-gettransaction-when-persisting-objects) that I cannot manually create transactions with an EntityManager that uses container-managed transactions. But isn't there any way now to manually ensure that the entity's attributes are persisted together (or not at all)? Or is this somehow already done automatically?

Comment: As long as your transaction isolation level is `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`, there is no chance that an entity can be read in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: "the transaction used for reading the entity ends after the entityManager.find()" - This doesn't sound right. Are you sure your method is running in a transaction? Did you use the [`@Transactional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) or [`@TransactionAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html#bnciu) annotations?

Comment: @HannoBinder: I got this information from the first link my question, which I found after googling for the IllegalArgumentException that I mentioned.
I'm not using the `@Transactional` or `@TransactionAttribute` annotations. Should I? If I got Szarpul's answer right, I don't need them.

Comment: @Keppil: Help a rookie out: The transaction isolation level is a setting of my RDMS, so if I know that the default transaction isolation level of my RDBMS (MySQL) is REPEATABLE_READ or READ_COMMITTED, I don't need to do anything (e.g. on the Java side), correct?

Comment: Btw, what does your `persistence.xml` look like? You may have to change JPA's transaction handling there, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331024/persistence-xml-different-transaction-type-attributes.

Comment: @Joe7: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @HannoBinder: 1. You were right, the method wasn't running in a transaction - see Szarpul's answer and our discussion. 2. Thanks for pointing out the transaction handling issue. My `persistence-unit` does not define any `transaction-type` explicitly, but injecting an `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceContext` works fine, so I assume the application is defaulting to "JPA" and I'm good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you run in EJB container and your transaction is managed by the container, every business method of your EJB bean is invoked inside a transaction, so as far as your isolation level of the transaction is no set to **Read uncommitted**, changes that where made in the method will be visible when the transaction commits, that is when the method finishes.

**UPDATE:**

As you don't use business methods it looks like your code is running without any transaction. In this case, every invocation of EnitytMangers method will create a new PersistenceContext. 
This is why you are getting exception. Entity that you get form `find` method is detached when next method of EntityManager is called (as new PersistenceContext is created).

Comment: Just to be sure I got this right: By "every business method of your EJB bean" you mean any method of the stateless session bean (MyService in my case), right?

Comment: Not any, business methods that you will have to implement from business interface. Here you have an example : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbod.html

Comment: Thanks for the link and the update. Again, just to be sure I got things right: If I extract an interface from the session bean, and this interface stays the only one that the session bean implements (or I explicitly annotate it with @Local or @Remote), then all methods mentioned in this interface will be considered business methods. This in turn means that each method call happens in a transaction. Correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What you have to have is: business interface(remote or local), stateless bean which implements this interface- than all implemented methods are business methods. After that you get your bean either by dependency injection or JNDI lookup. How to inject ejb bean- you have to google it.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. :-) And a business method is automatically invoked inside a transaction, as you answered earlier.

Comment: Yes, to be more specific: "Typically, the container begins a transaction immediately before an enterprise bean method starts and commits the transaction just before the method exits". - as the spec. says: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: OK, I extracted an interface from my stateless session bean now. Just as a little test, I left the `entityManager.lock()` lines in the method on the first test. Indeed the `IllegalArgumentException` didn't happen again, from which I conclude that the transaction was still open after the `entityManager.find(entityClass, id)` call, as expected.